# python list to database column (sqlite)

Tags: python, list

I have a list called

```
fullpricelist=[373.97, 381.0, 398.98, 402.98, 404.98, 457.97, 535.99, 550.97, 566.98]
```

I would like to write this list into a slqlite database column, I found the following code from another question and changed it to my situation.

```
cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO cardata (fullprice) VALUES (?)""", 
                   zip(fullpricelist))
```

My current script is this

```
for name, name2, image in zip(car_names, car_names2, images):
    cursor.execute(
        "insert into cardata (carname, carmodel, imageurl, location, Fro, T, companyid) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
        (name.text, name2.text, image.get_attribute('src'), location, pickup_d, return_d, Rental_ID)
    )
```

But now I am confused how to add these codes together

Answer (score 1):

In your second piece of code, execute() is called and one specific object is stored in the database each loop iteration. This is slow and inefficient.

```
for price in fullpricelist:
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO cardata (fullprice) VALUES (?)""", price)
```

executemany() reads from an iterable and adds each element of the iterable to the database as a distinct row. If you add many elements to a database and care about efficiency, you want to use executemany()

```
cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO cardata (fullprice) VALUES (?)""", fullpricelist)
```

If you want to include the other columns in your question, your code will be

```
cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO cardata (carname, carmodel, imageurl, location, Fro, T, companyid) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", 
        [
             [name.text for name in car_names], 
             [name.text for name in car_names2], 
             [image.get_attribute('src') for image in images], 
             [location]*len(car_names), 
             [pickup_d]*len(car_names), 
             [return_d]*len(car_names), 
             [Rental_ID]*len(car_names)
        ]  
    )
```

This assumes all values for location, pickup_d, return_d and Rental_ID are the same, as you did not provide a list of the values.

Comment: I am getting this error. cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO cardata (fullprice) VALUES (?)""", fullpricelist) sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 6 supplied